# Did Suou lose her human emotions in Darker than Black?

Tags: darker-than-black

I finished episode four just now. When Suou became a contractor in the train yard, did she get the rationality of a contractor, or did she retain her emotions like Hei? This is confusing for me.

Comment: It's been shown in the later series that by various contractors that they have emotions. It's not that contractor lose their emotions when they gain their powers, it's that  those feelings do not play a prominent role in their thought processes. In other words, they but logic before their feelings and typically only think for themselves, unless there is benefit to them helping others.

Answer (score 3):

Contractors don't lose their emotion, they just become more logical which conflicts with emotion, there is evidence to support this but obvious one is with Mina whose sexual preference is towards women however her obeisance is sexual contact, such as kissing, with men only yet she will kiss women, while most of the time it's to "get rid of the taste" from kissing a guy she has feeling towards Yoko.

With Suou, later in the series when her, Hei and July are in the hotel, when she and July are in bed and July has fallen asleep she admits to Hei that despite being a contractor she hates him.

Also Hei and Suou is that they're not proper Contractors as both obtain their powers from Bai who first merges with Hei during Heaven's War using her contractor powers and is then drawn into the Meteor Core around Suou's neck when Hei was caught in that trap and Hei has always been rational since before becoming a Contractor so he could support Bai so his personality isn't the result of Bai